# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting this error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first". I have tried using command but still can't fix this issue. The code I am using is as follows

```
{
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";
    queryStr = "select * from mydata.items;";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    using (MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
   {
       MyAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
       using (DataTable dTable = new DataTable())
    {
        MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    }
   }
}
```

I was originally trying below code (without using command).

```
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";
    queryStr = "select * from mydata.items;";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();        
    MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    conn.Close();
```

But both of the codes are giving exactly the same error (i.e. There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.)
Your help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think (in either sample) that you need the `cmd.ExecuteReader();` line? The one that opens a data reader, that the error message is telling you about, and that you then ignore/leak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of dataset will be more handy and efficient rather than table.Even you can cache it.
Also no need to use using construct because MySqlAdapter's fill method does it everything for you like

i)Open the connection. ii)Read the command ii)Execute the command ii)close the connection

```
 using ()
  {
   if(Cache["mydata"]==null)
    {
            queryStr = "";
            queryStr = "select * from mydata.items;";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();           
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;        
            DataSet ds =new DataSet();
            MyAdapter.Fill(ds);
            Cache["mydata"]=ds;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();                  
     }
else
  {
             GridView1.DataSource = (DataSet)Cache["mydata"];
             GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line creates a DataReader that you're not closing:

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Just remove the whole line, it's useless in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error is gone. But still not getting anything on display yet.

Comment: if its a webform, you may also have to call `GridView1.DataBind();`, that or `dTable` is null.